# How can I use yii widget nested another widget?

Tags: yii, widget, nested

```
class CommonHeaderWidget extends CWidget {

  public function run() {
```

// I want use Another widget here,
// but it's no use like this:

```
 $this->getController->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar', array(
        'items' => array(
            array(
                'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
                'items' => array(
                    array('label' => 'mall', 'url' => '#'),
                    array('label' => 'Join', 'url' => #),                        
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

// end.

```
$this->render('commonHeader');

  }
}
```

Then,I put the widget TbNavbar in commonHeader view ,it's no use too! How can I do?

Comment: I'm doing something similar in a current project of mine without problems. Can you describe what happens when you run the code?

Comment: Maybe this is too obvious but is "$this->getController" really the code your are using? You forgot the () to call the method or you could use "$this->controller" to do the same

Comment: Thanks **[ragingprodigy]http://stackoverflow.com/users/1875124/ragingprodigy** and **[Haensel]http://stackoverflow.com/users/1334352/haensel**,I read and do as all of you said,it worked.First,delete  **getController** method,because **Widget** has no method called that ,then delete **render** method ,it's no use in the case.Thanks again.

Comment: It should be correct. Is there any errors? Or Maybe use the with `CController::widget()`.

Comment: Thanks [http://stackoverflow.com/users/926639/shgninc] for your attention,This question has been solved, but you've given me a good idea, the pointer is the relation of class and method.